# Drupal Node relationships

Tags: php, drupal

I have two nodes, one is kind of a parent to the other node. For example, I'm displaying information about Plants. There are two nodes, Plant_Parent which has the latin name and some common names which is moderated, and then there is the Plant_Info which is not moderated and it has information like bloom time, growing experience, water requirements, stuff that's user specific. However, I want to be able to display the two together, i.e. someone selects a Plant_Parent node, and all the plant_info nodes are display as well.

Drupal doesn't seem to support this, is there a why I can do this?

Comment: it looks like a typical case of categorization, why don't you use categories?

Answer (score 2):

The heavily-used CCK module has a Node Reference field type that's perfect for this.

Answer (score 2):

Node reference as ceejayoz says can do two nodes displayed together. However you could also just have different permissions on fields within a node. Have a look at content_permissions which is part of CCK, or look at the sparsely documented [hook_field_access()](http://api.zzolo.org/api/function/content_permissions_field_access/drupal-6) if you wish to have even more custom permissions.